# Show that series $0.d_{ 1 }d_{ 2 }d_{ 3 }d_{ 4 }...=\frac { d_{ 1 } }{ 10 } +\frac { d_{ 2 } }{ 10^2 } +\frac { d_{ 3 } }{ 10^3 } +...$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

The decimal representation of a number $0.d_{ 1 }d_{ 2 }d_{ 3 }d_{ 4 }...$ (where the digit $d_i$ is one of the numbers $0, 1, 2, ...,9$) is that

$$0.d_{ 1 }d_{ 2 }d_{ 3 }d_{ 4 }...=\frac { d_1 }{ 10 } +\frac { d_2 }{ 10^2 } +\frac { d_3 }{ 10^3 } +\frac { d_4  }{ 10^4 } +...$$

Show that this series always converges.

What I did:

Since $0\le d\le 9$, we know that our series will be:

$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac {d_n}{10^n} }=\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }d_n{ (\frac {1}{10} })^n$$

Thus, this is a geometric series with $|r|<1$, therefore it will always converge.

---

Please let me know if my explanation is correct. I already know that the series will always converge. I just want to make sure that my reasoning is correct.

Comment: $\sum d_n(1/10)^n$ is not geometric, but $\sum d_n(1/10)^n\le \sum 10(1/10)^n$

Comment: You do not know that the series is geometric. For instance, there is no reason why $$\frac{d_2/100}{d_1/10}=\frac{d_3/1000}{d_2/100}$$ should hold in general.

Comment: @Arthur I made a huge typo in the title and in my post. I am sorry! Will correct it right now! That probably made my solution seem very stupid.

Comment: @NickLiu 

I fixed the post and title.

Comment: @NickLiu If I was given that $d$ is one of the numbers $(0, 1, 2, ..., 9)$, why are you comparing it to a series who first term is $\le 10$?

Comment: so that the sequence $(\sum_{n=1}^{i} d_n(1/10)^n)_{i\in \Bbb N}$ is bounded above and increasing, thus $\sum d_n(1/10)^n$ converge

Comment: @NickLiu, wouldn't it have to be $\sum d_n(1/10)^n < \sum 10(1/10)^n$, since $d_i$ can never actually be $10$? Sorry, I am just confused by that.

Comment: @NickLiu Would it be wrong to write $\sum d_n(1/10)^n < \sum 10(1/10)^n$?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer it is correct to put  the "$<$" sign

Comment: @NickLiu Would $\sum d_n(1/10)^n\le \sum 9(1/10)^n$ be correct as well? I am just confused since I want to get an $r$ where $|r|<1$

Comment: @NickLiu This is where I found the aforementioned comment:

http://faculty.wwu.edu/curgus/Courses/226_201210/Decimal.pdf

Comment: @cherry_developer yes, I wrote down the inequality pretty causally because the right hand side is not the main point actually.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\forall i , 0\le d_i\le 9$ so we can say $\forall i, d_i<10$

Which gives us : $\forall i , \forall k, 0<{d_i\over 10^k} < {10\over 10^k} = 10^{1-k}$

We can apply the sum : $0<\sum_{k=1}^n {d_k\over 10^k} < \sum_{k=1}^n 10^{1-k}$

Now we can see $u_n = 10^{1-n}$ is a geometric function of 'reason' (not sure of the english word) $10^{-1}<1$ thus $\sum_{k=1}^n 10^{1-k}$ converge and by comparaison of two positive series, $\sum_{k=1}^n {d_k\over 10^k}$ converges too.